# How can I make a countdown timer that displays minutes in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a countdown timer that displays minutes. Unfortunately, when I try to run it the minutes go down way faster than they should. The timerinterval is at 1000 (1 second). How can I fix this and make it a functioning timer? I've tried many different ways to make this countdown, so any suggestions on an alternate method are alright as well. I have a different label for minutes and seconds at the moment.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim CurrentTime As Integer

    Private Sub btnQuit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnQuit.Click
        End
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_MouseMove()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
        tmrStart.Enabled = True
        CurrentTime = 180


    End Sub

    Private Sub tmrStart_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrStart.Tick
        CurrentTime = CurrentTime - 1
        lblSeconds.Text = (CurrentTime / 3) * 10
        If CurrentTime < 180 And CurrentTime > 120 Then
            lblMinutes.Text = "2"
        ElseIf CurrentTime < 120 And CurrentTime > 60 Then
            lblMinutes.Text = "1"
        ElseIf CurrentTime < 60 And CurrentTime > 0 Then
            lblMinutes.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub lblSeconds_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblSeconds.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CurrentTime = 180
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Hard to guess why you liked dividing by 3, there are 60 seconds in a minute.  So use lblSeconds.Text = CStr(CurrentTime Mod 60): lblMinutes.Text = CStr(CurrentTime \ 60).  The backslash is not a typo.

Comment: I divided by 3 as my total seconds are 180. That code also worked, by the way, thanks.

Comment: If you work out what is actually happening .. when current time is 180, you're dividing that by 3 to get 60 and then multiplying that result by 10 to get 600. on the next tick of the timer, currentTime is 179, so divide it by 3 and multiply by ten, you get 596.66666666. Your code can't possibly work. No offense intended of course :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with time, then you'd be better using the `Date` type. If would make your code much cleaner if you declared `currentTime` as a date - like so ..

```
Dim CurrentTime As Date
```

Then, where you assign a value to it you would use

CurrentTime = #0:3:0#

-- 3 minutes ..

Then change the following subs to these

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    tmrStart.Enabled = True
    CurrentTime = #0:3:0#
End Sub

Private Sub tmrStart_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrStart.Tick
    CurrentTime = CurrentTime.AddSeconds(-1)
    lblSeconds.Text = CurrentTime.Second.ToString
    lblMinutes.Text = CurrentTime.Minute.ToString
    If CurrentTime = #0:0:0# Then
        tmrStart.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Much cleaner and easier to see what is going on. Also your statements to decide which minute is displayed in your original code appear to work correctly, but when the number of seconds remaining is exactly 120, or 60, the labels don't actually get updated. It doesn't matter too much in your code, but to be "logically" correct, they should be

```
    If CurrentTime < 180 And CurrentTime >= 120 Then
        lblMinutes.Text = "2"
    ElseIf CurrentTime < 120 And CurrentTime >= 60 Then
        lblMinutes.Text = "1"
    ElseIf CurrentTime < 60 And CurrentTime >= 0 Then
        lblMinutes.Text = ""
    End If
```

Final small thing, there is nothing in your code to disable the timer then the time remaining gets to 0

Don't be put off by these things - humans are fallible - Me as much as anyone else.

Comment: It is not a date, it is a TimeSpan.

Comment: Fair enough .. yes TimeSpan could also be used :)